# Running files on HFDS through a python script via PIG

Tags: python, hadoop, scripting, apache-pig, hdfs

I have an HDFS folder that contains 20 GB worth of .xml files. I want to run them through a python script (script.py) which takes a .xml file, makes changes, and outputs a new one. Example, on a .xml file that is local:

```
python script.py file1.xml > file2.xml
```

I have the following PIG script:

```
input_data = LOAD 'hdfs/path/to/input/dir';
DEFINE mycommand `python script.py` ship('/path/to/my/script.py/');
updated_data = STREAM input_data THROUGH mycommand PARALLEL 20;
STORE updated_data INTO 'hdfs/path/to/output/dir';
```

When I run the PIG script (./pig /path/to/pig/script.pig), I get the error:

```
Backend error message
ERROR 2055: Received Error while processing the map plan: 'python script.py 
(stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)'
failed with exit status: 1
```

Which leads me to believe there is an issue with 'mycommand'. Do we need to specify that script.py takes a .xml file as input (like we did on local)? If so, what would the syntax be?

```
DEFINE mycommand `python script.py input_data > updated_data(?)`
```

Or is there some other issue Im not seeing?

Comment: Why not to process your files as it go and then mv them with bash? Also I am not sure that you can LAOD  .xml wtih the default Pig UDF. More info is here http://blog.mortardata.com/post/61678005593/xml-pig-loader

Comment: I could just copy the data to local, run it through the python script, and then push it back to HDFS, but that will take much longer. I was thinking a pig script would make the process go much faster @madbitloman

Comment: I don't think it would work this way. Streaming will call the provided command on each record in the relation. So in your case, the relation would need to contain a list of the XML files.